# Reduction type at p=2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E:y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ be an integral, minimal model for an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. The discriminant of $E$ is $\Delta = -2^4(4A^3+27B^2)$ so $E$ always has bad reduction at $p=2$. A search on the LMFDB suggests that this reduction is always additive. Is this the case, and if so why?

My current understanding is that a curve has additive reduction at $p$ if the reduced curve has a triple root. This occurs for some curves of this form, e.g $E_1: y^2=x^3+2$, but not for all, e.g $E_2:y^2=x^3+1$. Both examples have additive reduction at 2 however. Is there perhaps a more general definition?

Many thanks for any guidance provided.

Comment: The problem is that in characteristics $2$ and $3$ you can't always put your curve into Weierstrass form. Less cryptically, you really need to find a $\mathbb{Z}$-model $V(f)\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{Z}$ with $f$ a *general* cubic--not one of the form you listed.

Comment: For the purposes of $p=2$ the curves look like $y^2+xy=x^3+Ax+B$ or $y^2+y=x^3+Ax+B$. The short form always gives a singular reduction mod two because $\partial F/\partial y=2y=0$ vanishes everywhere.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Could you possibly describe how you would show that the reduction for the short form is additive? I now understand that the analysis of double/triple roots fails in char$(K) = 2$.